# How to manually set value of HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am creating an Asp.NET MVC 5 application. For this project, I am trying to implement a custom authentication mechanism (i don't want to use Forms Authentication / OWIN etc. external providers)

I created a custom authorize attribute as follows:

```
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Class | System.AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class myAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {            
        if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            httpContext.Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login");
        }                            

        return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    }
}
```

And in my Login action, I am trying to change the value of

```
HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

But it is read only and I am unable to change the value. Can I change its value manually or am I making a logical mistake.

Comment: Is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity helpful?

Comment: Yes it is a great article, but it covers a complete replacement of a provider which in fact, exceeds my knowledge about the topic. But I will keep that in my mind. Thanks.

Comment: @emumcu did any of the answers below help?  An upvote or accepted answer would really help.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can achieve this by manually settings HttpContext.User:

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity("Custom");
HttpContext.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
```

It's important to set a custom `authenticationType`. In the example above, I just used the string "Custom", but it can be anything you want.

With that, `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` will be `true`.

For something more complicated, you can add claims like this:

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim("UserId", "123", ClaimValueTypes.Integer32)
}, "Custom");

HttpContext.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
```

This results in:

```
HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true;
int.Parse(((ClaimsIdentity)HttpContext.User.Identity).ValueFromType("UserId")) == 123;
```

Comment: I was trying to set `Identity.Name` and if you want, this is how to do it: create claim as  `new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "TheNameYouWant")`

Comment: This works for me and for what I needed it for but can I check that it only applies to the current request? In my case I needed to access the `HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context.User.Identity.Name` during the same request as the forms authentication but it wass not available until subsequent requests.

Answer (score 2):

My answer may no suit you perfectly but it may help.
In my ASP.NET Core MVC application, administrators need to impersonate other users.
It is an intranet application and obviously users are authenticated by Windows authentication.
It is done thanks to an ajax request to this controller action :

```
public async Task<JsonResult> UserImpersonation(IdentityExtension userIdentity)
```

IdentityExtension is a custom class of which you can observe the signature below :

```
public class IdentityExtension : IIdentity
{       
    public IdentityExtension()
    { }
    public IdentityExtension(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
    public string AuthenticationType => "Kerberos";

    public bool IsAuthenticated => true;

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

UserImpersonation method returns the success state of ReplaceUser method, wich updates HttpContext.User this way :

```
this.HttpContext.User = identity as ClaimsPrincipal;
return true;
```

identity being an instance of IdentityExtension.

I hope my solution can be adapted to your use case !

Answer (score 0):

We can see, from the source code:

```
 /// <summary>
 /// Gets a value that indicates if the user has been authenticated.
 /// </summary>
 public virtual bool IsAuthenticated
 {
     get { return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_authenticationType); }
 }
```

so, it means when we have a null _authenticationType, IsAuthenticated will always be false;
otherwise, it will be true.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the HttpContext to persist and be able to fetch claims afterward, do the following. I'll be using Cookie Authentication as the authenticationType.

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, ClaimTypes.Name, ClaimTypes.Role);
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, TempData["Username"].ToString()));
var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal, new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = true });
```

Answer (score -1):

you can't use FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Of course it is one of the possible solutions, but I prefer not to use it.