# .NET 7 Blazor MAUI - Require Authentication with Azure User Logins

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, blazor, maui

I am developing a Blazor MAUI application, and I am trying to require users in my organization to login with their Microsoft work account in order to access the application. I have not been able to find much documentation about authentication within Blazor MAUI, and have been struggling to get a solution working.

Currently, I have been following Microsoft's docs about Blazor Hybrid authentication: [ASP.NET Core Blazor Hybrid authentication and authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/security/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=maui). I have added the following class `ExternalAuthStateProvider.cs`:

```
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;

public class ExternalAuthStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private readonly Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationState;

    public ExternalAuthStateProvider(AuthenticatedUser user) => 
        authenticationState = Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(user.Principal));

    public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync() =>
        authenticationState;
}

public class AuthenticatedUser
{
    public ClaimsPrincipal Principal { get; set; } = new();
}
```

And have replaced the `return builder.Build();` in `MauiProgram.cs` with:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
builder.Services.TryAddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, ExternalAuthStateProvider>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<AuthenticatedUser>();
var host = builder.Build();

var authenticatedUser = host.Services.GetRequiredService<AuthenticatedUser>();

/*
Provide OpenID/MSAL code to authenticate the user. See your identity provider's 
documentation for details.

The user is represented by a new ClaimsPrincipal based on a new ClaimsIdentity.
*/
var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());

authenticatedUser.Principal = user;

return host;
```

From here, I am not sure what code to add in `MauiProgram.cs` to connect to my Azure app registration. I have followed multiple guides for configuring my Azure app registration, but have not seen any C# code similar to the code above, so I am confused on how to implement the connection here.

~ Aside from this method, the only other documentation I have found for Blazor MAUI is this video: [MSAL Auth in MAUI Blazor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rJH43uOwZm0&t=1266s). However, I'm wondering what other options there are for social logins without being forced to use Azure AD B2C? I am working on a handful of other projects where I do not have access to Azure AD B2C, and do not want to be forced to use the service.

Comment: See following  : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#authorizeview-component

Comment: This is a roadblock I've had for last few days. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Anil unfortunately no, and I have not revisited this project in a while. If I do and find a solution, I will post it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also found Microsoft docs to be lacking on the subject when it comes to integrating MSAL with Blazor Hybrid. I spent a few days digging through various resources online to come up with something that worked.

Here's a wrapper that includes the MSAL.NET code to authenticate the user. You'll have to create `IAuthenticationService` which I left out.

```
public class AuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
{
    // I recommend storing this in appsettings.json and grabbing it from IConfiguration instead
    private readonly IPublicClientApplication authenticationClient;
    private readonly string[] _scopes = new[] { "User.Read" };
    private readonly string _tenantId = "[TENANT ID HERE]";
    private readonly string _clientId = "[APP ID HERE]";

    public AuthenticationService()
    {
        authenticationClient = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(_clientId)
            .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, _tenantId) // Only allow accounts in the tenant to authenticate
            .WithRedirectUri($"msal{_clientId}://auth")
            .Build();
    }

    public async Task<AuthenticationResult?> AcquireTokenSilentAsync()
    {
        var accounts = await authenticationClient.GetAccountsAsync();

        AuthenticationResult? result;
        try
        {
            result = await authenticationClient.AcquireTokenSilent(_scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                .ExecuteAsync();
        }
        catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
        {
            // Acquiring silently failed; need to acquire the token interactively
            result = await AcquireTokenInteractiveAsync();
        }

        return result;
    }

    public async Task<AuthenticationResult?> AcquireTokenInteractiveAsync()
    {
        if (authenticationClient == null)
            return null;

        AuthenticationResult result;
        try
        {
            result = await authenticationClient.AcquireTokenInteractive(_scopes)
                .WithTenantId(_tenantId)
                .ExecuteAsync()
                .ConfigureAwait(false);

            return result;
        }
        catch (MsalClientException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Now your state provider can inject `AuthenticationService` to get the token.

There are a few weird quirks in here for `ClaimsPrincipal` that I could only get working with a hack so the user context would actually recognize the change in authentication state.... definitely some room for improvement.

```
public class ExternalAuthStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private readonly IAuthenticationService _authenticationService;
    private ClaimsPrincipal _currentUser;

    public ExternalAuthStateProvider(IAuthenticationService authenticationService)
    {
        _currentUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());
        _authenticationService = authenticationService;
    }

    public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync() =>
        Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_currentUser));

    public Task LogInAsync()
    {
        var loginTask = LogInAsyncCore();
        // Use BlazorWebView to update the auth state
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(loginTask);

        return loginTask;

        async Task<AuthenticationState> LogInAsyncCore()
        {
            _currentUser = await LoginWithExternalProviderAsync();

            return new AuthenticationState(_currentUser);
        }
    }

    private async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> LoginWithExternalProviderAsync()
    {
        var authResult = await _authenticationService.AcquireTokenInteractiveAsync();

        // Authentication failed, return the current logged out user state
        if (authResult == null) return _currentUser;

        List<Claim> claims;
        ClaimsPrincipal authenticatedUser;

        // For some reason AAD sets "name" as the claim type for the user name and not ClaimsType.Name...
        // This is a workaround since context.User.Identity only recognizes ClaimsType.Name
        var name = authResult.ClaimsPrincipal.FindFirst(c => c.Type == "name")?.Value;
        if (name != null)
        {
            claims = claims = authResult.ClaimsPrincipal.Claims.ToList();
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, name));
            authenticatedUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims));
        }
        else
        {
            // Another interesting quirk, we MUST recreate the ClaimsPrincipal instead of using authResult.ClaimsPrincipal directly
            // according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/security/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=maui
            authenticatedUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(authResult.ClaimsPrincipal.Claims));
        }

        // Here's the access token
        var token = authResult.AccessToken;

        return await Task.FromResult(authenticatedUser);
    }

    public void Logout()
    {
        _currentUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_currentUser)));
    }
}
```

Finally, we can add these services to `MauiProgram.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, ExternalAuthStateProvider>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthenticationService>();
```

As for integrating the authentication service with Blazor, see the answer from javiercn in [this](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/2529), as well as my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72308400/net-maui-blazor-hybrid-msal-authentication/76622716#76622716).

Hopefully this leaves you with a good start if you choose to pick up where you left off with your project.

Resources:

- [ASP.NET Core Blazor Hybrid authentication and authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/security/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=maui)
- [ASP.NET Core Blazor authentication and authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#authorizeview-component)
- [github.com/carlfranklin/MsalAuthInMauiBlazor](https://github.com/carlfranklin/MsalAuthInMauiBlazor/tree/master)
- [Desktop app that calls web APIs: Acquire a token interactively](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-desktop-acquire-token-interactive?tabs=dotnet)
- [Get a token from the token cache using MSAL.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-acquire-token-silently)

Comment: Thanks for revisiting this and providing a solution. I will revisit my project soon and see how it works.

Comment: If this answered your question please hit the check mark. Good luck with the project!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into an issue where the authenticatedUser.isauthenticated is false.

The issue can be fixed by adding a string to the ClaimsIdentity

```
authenticatedUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Password"));
```

[More information about the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55121548/how-to-manually-set-value-of-httpcontext-user-identity-isauthenticated)